# remote DBG via TCP cannot find bounds of current function

Tags: c++, linux, debugging

I am trying to remotely debug a linux machine c++ hello world code from a windows client. I am Debuging from windows 7 to Beaglebone Black running ubuntu. I remember i had similar issues when i was debuging from a linux machine to raspberry pi host.

The problem is, when i start debbuging i cant step anywhere because i am getting ths message:
[image]

I provided the gdb debugger and executable for the client program within i debug from but i have no clue what else shuld i give? One thing is that when i instead of stepping continue through the code, i finally get to my breakpoint but i get segfault at the end anyways. How can i provide the apropriate info for the debugger?
Any help would be really aprichiated.

Comment: Did you comple your program with `-O0 -g`?

Comment: Did you try to locally on the Linux machine? This could help to isolate the problem.

Comment: I tried adding now -O0 -g, but it havent helped. Also harper, i cant run it on linux because im on windows now. So cant run it localy. If i click "continue until line cursor is on" at the start of the debug it goes to the 1st breakpoint. But that also doesnt always work. Is there a way to automaticaly hit the 1st breakpoint when the debug started?